# Homework on Quotient Topology

Tags: general-topology

Yet another question from Munkres.

Define an equivalence relation on the plane $X =\mathbb{R^2}$ as follows:

$x_0 \times y_0 \sim x_1 \times y_1$ if $x_0 + y_0^2 = x_1 +y_1^2$

Let $X^*$ be the corresponding quotient space. It is homeomorphic to a familiar space: what is it? (Hint: Set $g(x,y) = x+y^2$)

Well I really need some help on getting started on this one, since my instructor covers relatively quickly on quotient topology so I am kind of stuck.

So now based on the hint given, $g$ is essentially a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $ \mathbb{R}$. My goal is to somehow find a homeomorphism between $X^*$ and some space. This is probably equivalent to finding a quotient map between $X^*$ and the unknown space. I am not sure if that is right, but I am trying to reread the part of quotient topology in Munkres. For the moment, any hint will be appreciated.

P/S: My lecturer does not cover stuff like saturated set, just probably two or three basic theorems on quotient topology. So I am guessing that the solution should not be too complicated.

Comment: if someone can comment on how I could utilize the function $g$ in the hint that will be really helpful

Comment: Take a closer look at theorem 22.2 (2nd edition). Let $X$=$\mathbb{R}^2$, $Y=X^*$ and $Z=\mathbb{R}$, with $g$ the map given in the hint. Now look at corollary 22.3 (2nd edition) and use the fact that $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Some other questions (solution verifications) about the same problem: [Munkres, §22, Exercise 4 (a). Proof verification.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1792285) and [Proving a given map to be a quotient map.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4608482)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Note that $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle\sim\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ iff $g(x_0,y_0)=g(x_1,y_1)$. In other words, $g$ is constant on $\sim$-equivalence classes and takes different $\sim$-classes to different real numbers. The quotient map $q:\Bbb R^2\to X^*$ does the same thing, if you replace *different real numbers* by *different points of* $X^*$. This suggests that you should try proving that $X^*$ is homeomorphic to the range of $g$, which is pretty clearly all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hint, I will definitely try doing it before getting back here