# Munkres, §22, Exercise 4 (a). Proof verification.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Define an equivalence relation on the plane $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
x_0 \times y_0 \sim x_1 \times y_1 \quad \mbox{if} \quad x_0 + y_0^2 = x_1 + y_1^2.
\end{align*}

Let $X^*$ be the corresponding quotient space. It is homeomorphic to a familiar space; what is it? [Hint: Set $g(x \times y) = x + y^2$.]

I want to know if the following resolution is ok.

Let $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x \times y) = x + y^2$. The map $g$ is continuous, because the addition and product are continuous functions. Furthermore $g$ is a surjective map, because for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is $x \times 0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $g(x \times 0) = x$. Now, $X^*$ is the collection of the subsets of $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of all the points $x \times y$ such that $z = x + y^2$, for every $z \in Z = \mathbb{R}$. Then

\begin{align*}
X^* = \{ g^{-1}(\{ z \}) \; | \; z \in \mathbb{R} \}.
\end{align*}

We prove that $g$ is a quotient map. Consider all the points $x \times 0$ of the plane $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$; these points belong to the line $\mathbb{R}$ (First coordinate of $\mathbb{R}^2$), taken as a subset of $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. Since $g(x \times 0) = x$, we can see that $g$ maps every point $x$ belonging to the line $\mathbb{R}$ to the same point $x$, and therefore $g$ is a retraction of $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ onto $\mathbb{R}$. And then, by exercise 2 (b), the function $g$ is a quotient map. Hence, by Corollary 22.3, pag. 142, of the Munkres book, it follows that there exists an homeomorphism $f : X^* \to \mathbb{R}$; and the familiar space is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: pretty good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a retraction from $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $\mathbb{R}$, because $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

But $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ is, by $g'(x,y) = (g(x),0)$.
So $g'$ is a quotient map (using exercise 2(b) if you like), and as $(x,0) \rightarrow x$ (the projection) is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, the composition of these maps, which is $g$, is also quotient.

Now you apply the Corollary.

Comment: What is $g'(x,y) = (g(x),0)$? I think $g$ is from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but you wrote $g(x)$.